# Data binding in HTML input in *ngFor in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using *ngFor to loop through an array of objects and displaying the value in the HTML. In the HTML, the value is displayed in a input element as I want the user to change the value if required and then have the changed value saved using a Save button. Unfortunately the data binding is not working at all. The values from the array are not displaying.  Here is my code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of rrReasons; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
<td>
  <input type="number" name=a{{index}} [(ngModel)]="rrReasons[index].signatory1">
</td>
```

And this is the json:

{
    "signatory1" : "1009648",
    "signatory2" : "1003444",
   }

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried

Comment: use data variable instead of rrReasons[index]

Comment: It's not clear where your array is? You've posted an object with two properties instead of an array.

Comment: Hey Kurt, the array is an array of Object, the Object is similar to the one I have given

Comment: You are iterating on `rrReasons` and you are using `[(ngModel)]="rrReasons[index].signatory1"`, you should instead use the `data` variable you created like this `[(ngModel)]="data.signatory1"`

Answer (score 3):

You are using `rrReasons[index].signatory1`. `index` isn't available as a variable inside the loop.

You should instead use `rrReasons[i].signatory1` or `data.signatory1`.

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of rrReasons; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <td>
      <input type="number" name=a{{i}} [(ngModel)]="rrReasons[i].signatory1">
    </td>
</table>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmscxv

Comment: Thanks Kurt, the demo looks good. I will try it in my code...

Answer (score 2):

Your TS code should be like

```
rrReasons = [{
    "signatory1": "1009648",
    "signatory2": "1003444",
  },
  {
    "signatory1": "1009649",
    "signatory2": "1003445",
  },
  {
    "signatory1": "1009650",
    "signatory2": "1003446",
  },
  {
    "signatory1": "1009651",
    "signatory2": "1003447",
  },
  {
    "signatory1": "1009652",
    "signatory2": "1003448",
  }
]
```

HTML code should be like

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of rrReasons; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
  <td>
    <input type="number" name=a{{index}} [(ngModel)]="data.signatory1">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Note: while you are looping an array then you have to use iterator value to get the actual object value.

Working Example:- [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1lygrq)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ngModel` for two way data binding. It will automatically keep your binding in sync.

I have created a working stackblitz instance here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kca94

You can read about NgModel about here - https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Please find snippit of code here:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of arr">
  <input [value]="element.value" [name]="element.value" [(ngModel)]="element.value" />
</div>
```

Typescript code here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  arr = [
    {id: 1, value: 'value1'},
    {id: 2, value: 'value2'},
    ]
}
```